# Android : Auth0 - How to work with dynamic package name, domain and scheme with Auth0?

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, auth0

So I am following [this document](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/android/00-login) to implement Okta in one of my Android App. After following it, its working fine. But the thing is, I do have an API that is giving domain, package name, scheme etc dynamically, like different values for different application's.

In above documentation, what I can see is app-level `build.gradle` file,

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.auth0.samples"

    // ...

    // ---> Add the next line
    manifestPlaceholders = [auth0Domain: "@string/com_auth0_domain", auth0Scheme: "@string/com_auth0_scheme"]
    // <---
}
```

So the question over here is, if these values are dynamically coming from API, then how can we update or set in the app as `build.gradle` values, specifically package names can't be set dynamically? So how can I set these values in auth0?

Any help will be appreciated.